# yarn command not found after installing via npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, npm, hadoop-yarn

As per the yarn installation for yarn v2, they want you to install using `npm install -g yarn`.  So I ran `sudo npm install -g yarn` on Ubuntu 20.04.  But after I do that, it says command not found.

```
❯ sudo npm install -g yarn

> yarn@1.22.10 preinstall /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yarn
> :; (node ./preinstall.js > /dev/null 2>&1 || true)


❯ yarn --version
zsh: command not found: yarn
```

Comment: Run it without `sudo`.  If you have your paths set up correctly then this issue is because of the users.

Comment: sometime you just miss the type of terminal your using zsh, bash etch.

Answer (score 41):

```
sudo npm install -g npm
```

then

```
sudo npm install -g yarn
```

**Then reboot your system.** That did it for me.
Before a reboot only sudo yarn worked. I tried looking at file permissions but everything seemed in order and the files were executable as expected. Nevertheless after a reboot it worked.

If you go to /usr/local/bin after the installation there's a link there to where yarn.js lives, as expected, and file permissions for it were also correct.

/usr/local/bin is added to $PATH, so it's surprising that it doesn't see the new cmd right away, but perhaps it didn't reload or map it until after the reboot? I don't know. But I just spent a good hour trying to figure this out so I'm posting what worked for me to spare other the hassle.

Comment: For future viewers, I deleted npm and npm_cache located in appdata/roaming prior to doing this as even this fix didn't solve the issue for me. After deleting, I ran these commands, restarted my pc, and voila, problem solved.

Comment: With this on Ubuntu 20.04 no reboot was required.

Comment: "npm install -g yarn" worked for me with no sudo and no restart

Answer (score 14):

**TL;DR**
If you are managing node via `nvm`, then probably the path to yarn binary is not included in the `$PATH` variable. You should add this -

```sh
# Add this at the end (or after the $NVM_DIR initialization)
#   in your profile - .bashrc | .zshrc | .profile, etc
export PATH="`yarn global bin`:$PATH"
```

at the end of your profile file (`.zshrc` for me) or at least after the `$NVM_DIR` initialization.

---

I have recently faced this issue and while searching for a solution, I landed up here.

> Here is what my environment looks like:
>
> - OS: Ubuntu 20.04
> - Shell: `zsh`
> - NodeJS: managing it via `nvm`, and NOT `apt`.

After going through all the answers, I was not keen on uninstalling anything. So I tried to dig a bit deeper.

I installed `yarn` via `npm install -g yarn` command. So the first thing I wanted to verify was the location of the `yarn` binary. To do this, I ran the command `where yarn` which lists the installation path for the `yarn` binary.

```sh
$ where yarn

/home/<user_name>/.nvm/versions/node/v16.11.1/bin/yarn
```

Then it hit me. In my `.zshrc` file, I had added the `yarn global bin` command (which spills out the directory of all the global packages installed by yarn) at the top like so:

```sh
# Top of my .zshrc file
export PATH="`yarn global bin`:$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

and as per the [installation instruction](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#install--update-script) of `nvm`, the `$NVM_DIR` (the variable which holds the `nvm` directory path) was added at the end of my `.zshrc` file.

***So when I was starting up my shell, it was actually trying to load the `yarn` command (present inside the `nvm` directory) even before loading the `$NVM_DIR` path.***

To solve this, I tweaked my `.zshrc` file and moved the `yarn global bin` command after the `$NVM_DIR` like this:

```sh
# Top of my .zshrc file
export PATH="$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH"

# ...
#
# Something in between
#
# ...

# Bottom of my .zshrc file
export NVM_DIR="${HOME}/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" # This loads nvm bash_completion

# Here is where I have added the path to yarn global
export PATH="`yarn global bin`:$$PATH"
```

I hope that this would be of help.

Comment: For me checking `nvm current` showed "none". After selecting a dedicated version, e.g. `nvm use 16` or 'lts' it worked again.

Comment: Does it work to run yarn inside the rc startup file if yarn isn't on the path?

Comment: Moving the NVM initialization above the yarn export did the trick!

Answer (score 9):

This solved it for me:

```
corepack enable
```

(if you get "Internal Error: EACCES: permission denied", run it with sudo)

This is also recommended by the Yarn documentation: https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/install

Answer (score 5):

Uninstall `cmdtest`:

```
sudo apt remove cmdtest
```

Then, run these commands:

```
curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt install yarn
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid reboot, use
`/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yarn/bin/yarn --version`

Answer (score 1):

The yarn documentation is missing a step, you need to restart your computer between this installation and running `yarn --version`.

This worked for me

Answer (score 1):

This is different from the problem OP had but you also get this error if you are working in an environment with multiple node versions. In this case, you need to have yarn installed under each version of node, like so

```
/node/vx.x.x/lib/node_modules/yarn/bin/yarn.js
```

After switching versions, if the above is not present then just run

```
npm install -g yarn
```

If yarn is installed under the version than the other answers will address the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a similar situation and here is how I solved it.

First I troubleshoot the current npm installation:

```
npm config -list
```

I had a `~/.npmrc` file that had a different prefix:

```
PREFIX=/opt/homebrew
```

That made my npm installation look for globally installed packages under `/opt/homebrew`.

In my case, I'm using a different npm installation (not with homebrew anymore). A simple fix is to remove this custom `PREFIX` from the `~/.npmrc` file and the problem was solved.

Now npm looks for globally installed packages under `/usr/local/bin/`.

Comment: The command probably should read `npm config list`. With `npm config -list` an error is reported.

Answer (score 0):

If you install yarn with sudo, it will only be available for the super user. So you can install it without prefixing the command with sudo and it will work fine.

`npm -i g yarn`

Answer (score -1):

I installed `yarn` with `npm install -g yarn` on git bash and I tested it with `yarn -v` that show the version of the installed yarn, but when I used `yarn start` it gives me this error

`C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Roaming\npm/node_modules/node/bin/node: line 1: This: command not found`

These are simple steps that I used to fix my problem on **Windows 10**:

1. Uninstall node.js
2. Restart your computer
3. Delete your `C:\Program Files\nodejs` and `C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Roaming\npm`
4. Install node.js again and check it with `node -v`
5. Start your vs code as an admin and write `npm install`
6. Write `yarn start`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

It means it's unable to find `yarn`.

To fix it do following steps

1. Know yarn path

```
where yarn
```

2. Update the path variables to include the path given by step 1.

In case of Mac, open `.zshrc` from your user directory and add following into it.

```
export YARN_PATH=<path_mentioned_in_step_1>
export PATH=$PATH:$YARN_PATH
```

In case of Windows, YARN PATH should be added in environment variable called `Path`

3. If you are getting this issue on VS Code terminal, Close and open the VS Code and run the command. If you are getting this issue on terminal, close and open the terminal and run the command.